# Cheap surveillance camera solution with Raspberry Pi 3b+

Tags: raspberry-pi, camera

I have a raspberry Pi 3b+ and I would like to attach a camera to it to create something like a CCTV for surveillance. I want to use 13MP f/2.2 aperture camera from a broken smartphone with Sony IMX135 CMOS sensor. Is this possible with raspberry Pi camera board? Can I just replace the raspberry Pi camera with my smartphone camera just like that? So far I have tried to find some ready made boards online but I do not know if the raspberry Pi board will do the job because my camera is 13MP whereas the camera with raspberry Pi camera board is usually 5MP. I am really confused.

Comment: Is it really worth it? Off the shelf security cameras are already dirt cheap now.

Comment: You are right. But I thought may be from a learning perspective it will give some value. Later the plan is to link it with cloud and access from anywhere.

Comment: I don't really want to throw money into something that I don't know will work or not.

Comment: Can you make it work? Sure. You may have to design a custom carrier board, custom drivers, kernel tweaking, etc. This would be one of those projects that you may sink a lot of money into before you figure out it's either beyond your skillset or your bank account. The camera may not have any documentation regarding interfaces or signal levels, so the first thing you should try doing is accumulating documentation to hash out a design...

Comment: This is of course unanswerable without engineering details of the camera.  As others have remarked, it's probably not a good idea.